# How To Make a Base Case for Recurrences.

Tags: proof-writing, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Hello I am working on solving a relation of the form to find time complexity of an algorithm:

(1)  $T(n) = 2T(\lfloor(\frac{n}{2})\rfloor +17) + n$

This is a homework problem and I am required to use the substitution method. I understand the substitution/induction part of the proof but I am struggling to understand how to form a proper base case.

We have to show that a base case for $n = 34$ holds true for all $ n <= 34 $.

I've seen other examples of problems that look similar such as:

(2)   $T(n) = 2T(\lfloor(\frac{n}{2})\rfloor) + n$

Where they use $n = 0$ as a base case, but this doesn't make any sense because what would be the use of running an algorithm on a data set of size 0?

I think it would help if someone could explain how to get a base case for a simpler problem such as equation 2, and then how the process changes for an equation like equation 1.

Thank You

Comment: The base case is determined by the problem at hand; it's not something you derive from the recurrence. For example, the recurrence $F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n-2)$ alone describes an entire family of sequences, each differentiated by the values of $F(0)$ and $F(1)$. Set $F(0) = 0$ and $F(1) = 1$, and you have the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: You wouldn't run the algorithm on a data set of 0, but that doesn't change the fact that doing so would take 0 time (assuming $T(n) = 0$). The point is that every other value of $T(n)$ follows from the recurrence and the chosen base case.